# How to remove SVG Files inline code of Wordpress Footer?

Tags: svg

After the latest update of WordPress version 5.9, I saw that there was a `svg` files added at the bottom of the page.

Can you please tell me, how to remove this?

What's the use of it?

[image]

Comment: This is not a WP5.9 issue.  Looking at two other sites that are updated to 5.9, no SVG is present in the footer.  Likely, your theme, a plugin or some other code specific to your site is adding those SVGs.

Comment: Really? But all my sites are impacted, and I had never seen this before the latest update. I request you to dig deeper.

Comment: Any element added to your code is managed by the theme. It will help us solve your issue if you tell us what theme you're using, the context of the code you'd like to remove and ideally a link to the actual page.

Comment: Read this, since version 5.8 the WP is adding junk in the footer.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/disabling-gutenberg-duotone-filter/

And there is no way to remove it.

Comment: @Pixelsmith 

I am using custom theme named Jargon -  you can find it my website: https://www.theidioms.com

Comment: Guys, this issue is related to `theme.json` file

Comment: This question shouldn't have been closed. It's not off-topic. It relates to the full site editor and block themes. I had the same question and the provided answer answered it.

Comment: @jdm2112 WordPress 5.8 introduced the SVG duotone filters that Juniper is asking about. Dig deeper next time. https://wptavern.com/duotone-filters-wordpress-5-8-puts-a-powerful-image-editing-tool-into-users-hands

Answer (score 3):

I've got the answer.
Create a new file in the root of your theme with the name `theme.json`

Add and save the following code into it:

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "settings": {
        "color": {
            "duotone": null
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Guys, please like my topic and answer so I can accept it as an answer and it will help others too.

Comment: You should be able to accept it as an answer now. I think there's just a two-day timeout for accepting your own answers, which is now passed.